# CakePHP - every seen this occuring: database session query repeating over and over and over

Tags: php, cakephp

This might be tough to read, but essential is does this over and over again (Repeats 14 times):

1. Select session id
2. Count session
3. Update session

16  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   1

17  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

18  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

19  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       1       1

20  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   1

21  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

22  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

23  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

24  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   1

25  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

26  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

27  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

28  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

29  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

30  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

31  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

32  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

33  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

34  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

35  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

36  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

37  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

38  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

39  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

40  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

41  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

42  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

43  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

44  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

45  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

46  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

47  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       2

48  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

49  DELETE `Session` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`expires` < 1440     0       1

50  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

51  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

52  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

53  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   1

54  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

55  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

56  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

57  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

58  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

59  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

60  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

61  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   1

62  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

63  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

64  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

65  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

66  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

67  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

68  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

69  DELETE `Session` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`expires` < 1281974807       0       1

70  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

71  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   1

72  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'      1   1   0

73  UPDATE `cake_sessions` SET `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330', `data` = '', `expires` = 1282010807 WHERE `cake_sessions`.`id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330'       0       1

74  SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `cake_sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `id` = '80f5f4f43334a7bc1446d06d143e6330' LIMIT 1      1   1   0

Comment: Oh comeon you expect us to decifer that?

Comment: I know. I just realized how hard it was to read. It's fixed now.

Comment: No upvotes, no accepted answers? No thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the cake core for this that has not been merged. The _read and _write methods for the cake_session are not correctly checking whether or not anything is in the _SESSION.

This patch corrects the issue:

http://github.com/dogmatic69/cakephp1x/commit/1940f80016ff136698e0e49f3097f8b6b29e9659

Thanks to dogmatic69